# Behavior of BJT collector current in saturation

Tags: current, bjt, theory, saturation, collector

1. Let's assume that we have NPN BJT with absolute maximum rating of collector current = 1A.
2. Let's assume that we have separate power supplies for base-emitter and collector-emitter.
3. The collector-emitter power supply is 10V (no internal resistance) and resistance between power supply and collector is 1 ohm, which results in maximum current of 10A if we forget about BJT for a while.

In the active state, we can control collector-emitter current via hFE & base current equation, so if we let 100mA through there will be 0,1V drop on resistor and 9,9V drop on C-E, right?

My question is: If we keep the base-emitter current high enough that transistor stays in saturation all the time, what will be the maximum current? Does the transistor limit the current somehow in saturation or can only the collector-emitter circuit limit it?

If Vce is 0,2V  we have (10-0,2)/1 = 9,8A maximum current, does that mean that 9,8A will go through or can the BJT limit it somehow, not considering thermal properties, damage etc., this is just a theoretical question?

Is it possible to increase the current in the BJT until it evaporate or will it be limited, not enough holes & electrons for such a high current or something?

Comment: Please draw a diagram with the circiut tool

Comment: "Absolute maximum rating" does not mean that the transistor makes it impossible to go above the absolute maximum value. It just means that the transistor will break rather quickly.

Answer (score 8):

You are basically asking what will happen if you try to exceed the absolute maximum collector current.

First, hFE is not constant. It will decrease substantially at high collector current, so there's a good chance that you'll never get close to 10A no matter how much current you shove into the base. That means a lot of collector current, maybe 3A or 4A, simultaneously present with a lot of Vce, resulting in a lot of power dissipation.

Take, for example, the [FMMT449](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/FMMT449.pdf)

[image]

Note that the graph does not show the (higher) forced beta required to maintain saturation- the Vce is 2V which is not saturated.

There is also a [safe operating area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_operating_area) curve:

[image]

Even worse than the simple thermal issues (say you could somehow hold the die at room temperature, regardless of of the massive power dissipation), bipolar transistors have a failure mode called "second breakdown" where concentration of current flow causes hot spots and device failure. That would likely be a factor in this case.

So, you'd likely either outright kill the part or damage it (characteristics and/or reliability) for most parts with that rating. The mechanism would be thermal (overheating and damage of the semiconductor causing a short) or second breakdown (similar fault symptom).

Comment: The underlying mechanism here [of hFE reduction] is *high level injection*, which limits the current density of a BJT.  Usually the pulsed Ic rating is comparable to this, so you simply can't expect to get more than this out of a device (at least in anything resembling normal operation).

Answer (score 6):

What 'saturation' means is that the external circuit is controlling the current, not the beta*Ib of the transistor.

Any particular transistor might be able to conduct 10 A if it has low enough residual resistance, for instant it's been designed as a power transistor.

With sufficient base drive to saturate the transistor, and a sufficiently beefy transistor, you would expect the VCE to drop to a 'saturation' level of well below 1 volt, and pull approaching 10 A through your 1 ohm resistor.

Do be aware that beta is by no means a constant, especially at high current. It's not uncommon for beta to fall to 20% of its low current value by the time the collector current reaches its maximum rating.

Comment: The OP's proposed circuit has a 1 ohm resistor between the collector and the +10V supply, and they're wondering if the BJT will pull nearly 10A through it (which would require a Vce of near zero volts).  i.e. if it can work like a power MOSFET if they push enough current through the base.

Answer (score 5):

Quote: "*My question is: If we keep the base-emitter current high enough that transistor stays in saturation all the time, what will be the maximum current? Does the transistor limit the current somehow in saturation or can only the collector-emitter circuit limit it?*"

Speaking about "saturation" we should remember the definition:

- The BJT is in saturation when the voltage Vce is smaller than the base-emitter voltage Vbe (Vce<Vbe). This means: The base-collector pn junction (npn case) is forward biased because of Vc<Vb (Vbc>0).
- As a result, the base current now consists of two parts (through the emitter as well as collector) and is, therefore, much larger than anticipated by the B factor. Therefore, this drastic increase of the base current is not the reason for saturation - in contrast, it is the result of saturation. The BJT is still a voltage-driven device - even under saturation.

Answer (score 4):

> If we keep the base-emitter current high enough that transistor stays in saturation all the time, what will be the maximum current? Does the transistor limit the current somehow in saturation or can only the collector-emitter circuit limit it?

Emitter and base resistances will limit what can be done. You can’t have the voltages arbitrarily high or else breakdown occurs during the slew-up phase of the stimulus.

So, as long as you can ramp things up and down very quickly, with power supply slew rates on the order of 1V/ns, and as long as you can get the transistor as a die or in a CSP, you may be able to see several amps on the collector for a very short time - and it will take more than 10V Vce probably.

The test pulses will last on the order of 10-100ns.

But that will take a die or a CSP mounted on a board laid out for high speed high current pulse sourcing.  I’m sure you could find a small transistor and run it way past the ratings for a very short time. Unfortunately, secondary breakdown can occur on the order of single ns IIRC if you try hard, and the test you imagine is definitely in the “trying very hard category”.

Comment: I'm not sure actually that breakdown occurs in relation to RB, RE or RC parameters.  But they are also lumped equivalents (e.g. in SPICE's BJT model) whereas the real device is distributed, and in any case we're talking current densities (and probably power densities as well) where localized heating can dominate. Case in point, C-E avalanche breakdown can sink 10-20A peak through a teeny 2N3904 junction, but only for some ns before local heating causes structural failure.

Answer (score 3):

## How to explain the transistor behavior

I feel like your question is conceptual; that is why my answer is also conceptual. If I am wrong, use the other answers and let this one remain as an addition to them.

To explain the transistor behavior in this mode in an intuitive way, I have used two electrical analogies of the transistor - *controlled resistor* and *controlled current source*.

## Variable resistor

This is the simplest idea of a transistor - *something that dissipates power and in which voltage is lost*. In principle, this resistance is non-linear, but for the purposes of this qualitative review, this is not essential. I will explain below what "saturation" is by considering the evolution of this resistance in the different operating modes of the transistor.

### Voltage divider concept

Accordingly, a common-emitter stage can be represented as a *voltage divider* with variable transfer ratio (gain).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkAlP6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Infinite resistance (off)

When the transistor is "off", the collector-emitter section has an infinitely high resistance (open circuit). No current flows, there is no voltage drop across the collector resistor Rc, and the output voltage Vce is equal to Vcc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE9x6P.png)</sup>

### Some resistance (active mode)

When the transistor begins to conduct, its "resistance" Rce, correspondingly the voltage Vce, begins to decrease.  Let's represent its middle value by Rce = Rc = 1 kΩ. So the transistor decreases the output voltage by decreasing its "resistance".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbczPx.png)</sup>

### Zero resistance (on)

Eventually the transistor exhausts its resistance and it becomes zero;  accordingly, the voltage becomes zero. As they say, "the transistor has saturated". The current stops changing and remains equal to its last value before saturation - Isat = Vcc/Rc = 10/1k = 10 mA (Ohm's law).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHTpNm.png)</sup>

From this point on, the "humble transistor" can do nothing more because it has no resistance. It used to be able to block the current by its resistance but now it cannot... and it cannot reduce its resistance less than zero.

### Negative resistance

However, let's fantasize a bit by continuing to change the resistance in this direction and finally make it **negative**: *infinite* -> *moderate* -> *zero* -> *negative*. This means that in order to go down below the zero voltage level, we have to insert a negative voltage instead of resistance, or as they figuratively call it, "negative resistance". We can do it with a behavioral voltage source -Rce controlled by the current Ic through it (current-to-voltage converter). For this purpose, open -Rce *parameters* window and set its voltage V(-Rc) to I(-Rc). This kind of negative resistance is known as "S-shaped" or "voltage inversion" because the voltage polarity is opposite to this across the same but "positive" resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLftr0.png)</sup>

Note that this additional source is connected in series and in the same direction as the power source; so its voltage is added to it. In fact, in this way we have increased the supply voltage.

So, after the transistor has exhausted its "resistance" (it has become zero) and "saturated", only Rc and Vcc remain in the circuit. Rc is constant; so the only way to continue increasing the current is to start increasing Vcc.

### Split supply

We can see this idea in split-supplied circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV2UsD.png)</sup>

## Current source

It is believed that this idea of the transistor is better. I agree with it only with the caveat that this is not a true source "producing" power but rather a *current-stabilizing nonlinear resistor*. Unfortunately, there is no such element in the CircuitLab library, only real current sources, and we have to take this into account when using it.

I will explain below what "saturation" is by considering the evolution of this collector current in the different operating modes of the transistor.

### Non-linear voltage divider

According to the *current source viewpoint*, the common-emitter stage can be represented as a variable current source Ice supplying the resistor Rc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVZ5b3.png)</sup>

### Zero collector current

When the transistor is "off", the current source representing it does not produce current. So, there is no voltage drop across the collector resistor Rc, and the output voltage Vce is equal to Vcc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3JGOd.png)</sup>

### Some collector current

When the transistor begins to conduct, the current source begins producing current. The voltage drop VRc begins increasing, and the complementary voltage drop Vce begins decreasing. In the schematic below, the middle value Ic = 5 mA is set, and the voltage drops are equal - Vce = Vc = 5 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUZDfd.png)</sup>

### Maximum collector current

When the current becomes 10 mA, all the voltage drops across Rc. The voltage across the transistor is zero and as they say, "the transistor has saturated". The current stops changing and remains 10 mA. But why? It is interesting to see it in the conceptual schematic below.

To understand why, we need to have an idea of ​​what is inside that circle with an arrow:-) So far, it was just a *variable resistance* as above that kept decreasing and thus increasing the current. Now it has become zero ("saturated"), and the current is equal to its last value before saturation - Isat = Vcc/Rc = 10/1k = 10 mA (Ohm's law).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWtdCV.png)</sup>

So, up to this point, the current source was not a "true power producing source" but a power consumer... and now the time has come to turn it into a true source.

### Above the maximum current

So let's open up the "circle with arrow inside" and insert an extra variable voltage source in series. Its voltage will be added to the power supply voltage and the current can be increased more.

Practically, this means remembering that CircuitLab's current source is a "true source" and we only need to increase its current (15 mA) above the maximum (10 mA).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9bRpt.png)</sup>

As you can see, the output voltage has dropped 5 V below zero.

## Conclusions

- In the broad sense of the word, "saturation" means that the regulating element of an amplifier configuration has exhausted its supply of regulating quantity.
- In transistor circuits, "saturation" means that the transistor has exhausted its "resistance" and thus its ability to increase the current any further.
- After the saturation point, a further increase in current requires an increase in the supply voltage or the insertion of an additional voltage source.

Comment: I hastened to place my answer, although incomplete, because I see that this question will also follow the fate of being closed... but it is so valuable and interesting...

Comment: Eh, those've been there a while. Close votes don't automatically go away, they have to be cleared from the queue (I think?). Which... check the queue, be the change you want to see ;)

Comment: @Tim Williams, I don't understand... What I see is that there are already 2 votes to close and only one more to really close the issue. It's hard to work like this, it's very annoying... It's midnight here and I'm in a hurry to write my answer before the question is closed...

Comment: I don't know why there's not the option on a post itself, but you're familiar with the queues right? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/close for users over 3k rep. Just skip through to find a thread you're interested in and vote on it.

Comment: @Tim Williams, I read something about it but still I don't know how to get to the Close votes queue.